# CMS sign in redirect to lms login page in open edx

Tags: openedx

After adding SSL in both URL LMS and CMS, I am facing one issue in CMS login.
 When I click on CMS sign in button then it is redirecting to LMS login page. Is there any configuration to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change the lines code below in the next file:

/edx/app/edxapp/edx-platform/cms/envs/common.py

```
#LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = EDX_ROOT_URL + '/home/'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = EDX_ROOT_URL + '/signin'
#LOGIN_URL = reverse_lazy('login_redirect_to_lms')
LOGIN_URL = EDX_ROOT_URL + '/signin'
```

And finally restart services with:

```
sudo /edx/bin/./supervisorctl restart lms cms edxapp_worker:
```

Greetings

Comment: Thanks you Jorge, I am facing the same problem when I logout cms.

Comment: It's not a good idea to make changes inside the code. as Chintan replied, this is a new feature in ironwood and can be disabled by configuration flags.

Answer (score 2):

Actually its a feature. (Assuming its ironwood install that you have done.)

Yes it is configurable.

You can do it by setting `DISABLE_STUDIO_SSO_OVER_LMS` flag.

Source: [Studio login via the LMS](https://edx.readthedocs.io/projects/open-edx-release-notes/en/latest/ironwood.html#studio-login-via-the-lms)

The community is not quite active in SO, you should try slack or mailing lists.

Comment: For anyone else having this problem, this flag is set in `cms.env.json` in the `FEATURES` object. You'll also need to restart the cms for it to take effect.

`/edx/bin/supervisorctl restart cms`